# How to get a user selection value in Watson Conversation

Tags: watson-dialog, watson-conversation

I am trying that the user selects an option from a `<select`> responded by Watson and store the value selected in a variable.

I have done that the Watson Conversation's response show a list of values to select (using HTML), but we don't get to store the value selected in a variable.

Is that possible?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-)
Please look at [ask]
and how to create a [mcve]. This will help to get useful answers.
I flagged this question for closing.

Answer (score 0):

Watson conversation is stateless. In order to capture user interaction/feedback, you need your UI/application layer to handle it.

You could create custom id/class tags in your select which the UI intercepts and knows how to respond to conversation.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible but, you have to be careful. So, this because the Conversation control the information in a **session named `context`**, and this is trafficked for application in all request/response (yeah, you need send for the `API` the conversation id in the interactions of the dialog).

In node for Dialog, you click in response/advanced and insert this:

```
"context" :
{
    "your_property": "values"
}
```